# Commutative propertie of multiplication on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm studying Real Analysis and trying to prove some properties of multiplication in $\mathbb{N}$.

In my case, I'm studying $\mathbb{N}$ where $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$, that is the natural numbers starting with 1.

I'm currently trying to prove the commutative law of multiplication with induction. Can someone please check if my proof is valid, and if it's not, tell me where I am missing something or doing anything wrong?

Notation and definitions used:

- $s(n) = n + 1$
- $s(n+p) = n + s(p)$
- $n \cdot 1 = n$
- $n \cdot s(m) = n\cdot m + n$

I've already proved and because of that can use:

- Associative law of sum
- Commutative law of sum
- Cancellation law of sum
- Distributive law of multiplication
- Associative law of multiplication

---

Here is my proof:

Define:
$$
X = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{ | } \forall m \in \mathbb{N}, m\cdot n = n\cdot m \}
$$
Checking de base case where $n = 1$:
$$
\begin{align*}
s(m\cdot 1) = s(m)\cdot 1&= s(m)\\
&= m+1\\
&= m\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1\\
&= 1(m+1)\\
&= 1\cdot s(m)
\end{align*}
$$
That covers all natural numbers except 1, since $1 \notin \text{im}(s)$. Because of that we show:
$$
\begin{align*}
1\cdot 1 &= 1\cdot 1\\
1 &= 1
\end{align*}
$$
Hence $1 \in X$.

Then I need to show that if $n \in X$, then $s(n) \in X$.

$$
\begin{align*}
m\cdot s(n) &= m(n+1)\\
&=m\cdot n + m\cdot 1\\
&=n\cdot m + 1\cdot m\\
&=(n+1)\cdot m\\
&=s(n)\cdot m
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore if $n \in X$ then $s(n) \in X$ and since $1 \in X$ too, we can conclude that $X=\mathbb{N}$.

---

Any kind of help is valid. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would be more explicit about the fact that for the base case you are trying to show that for any $m$:

$$1\cdot m = m \cdot 1$$

and that you do this by induction on $m$

Moreover, you should start out by:

$$s(m) \cdot 1 = s(m) = m + 1...$$

and also add the all important step:

$$m \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 \overset{Inductive \ Hypothesis}{=} 1 \cdot m + 1 \cdot 1 \overset{Left-Distribution}{=} 1 \cdot (m +1)$$

Also, I am wondering: Do  you have both left-distribution:

$$x \cdot (y +z) = x \cdot y + x \cdot z$$

*and* right-distribution:

$$(y +z) \cdot x = y \cdot x + z \cdot x$$

Because you are using right-distribution when going from $n \cdot m + 1 \cdot m = (n+1) \cdot m$

Comment: But I did that, didn't I? I showed that when we're looking for $n = 1$ we need to show that for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ it will follow that $m\cdot 1 = 1\cdot m$. I showed it explicitly for $m = 1$, and using $s(m)$ I showed it for all natural numbers different than $1$. What is incorrect my friend? Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoReis you are right ... but maybe you should be a little more explicit about the fact that you prove this specific statement and that you do this by induction on $m$

Comment: Thank you! About the right distribution... I can use it because of my induction hypothesis can't I? I mean, since I am assuming that I have $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we know that $m\cdot n = n \cdot m$. We also know that it applies for $n=1$ because we've shown that $1 \in X$ then it follows that $m(n+1)=(n+1)m$. Isn't that enough to conclude the last step? Thanks again!!

Comment: @BrunoReis No, the inductive hypothesis only gives you $m \cdot n = n \cdot m$ .. it doesn't give you right- distribution, and wihout it you cannot go from $n \cdot m + 1 \cdot m$ to $(n+1)\cdot m$

Comment: @BrunoReis so ... I think you will first have to prove right-distribution ... presumably by doing induction on the right term